# Are these interchangeable (continuous)?

Tags: do

Concerning the usage of the following forms "to do" and "to be doing," are the continuous ones correct?

> - There is nothing to laugh at.
> - There is nothing to be laughing at.
> - There isn't much to talk about.
> - There isn't much to be talking about.

Comment: What do Google Ngrams for {nothing to laugh at,nothing to be laughing at,much to talk about,much to be talking about} suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The first and third phrases seem more common, and the second and fourth phrases are slightly more confusing, but they still work.